# why i receive this error (Unable to resolve "expo-av") when trying to run a react-native-gifted-chat project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

This is the error:
Unable to resolve "expo-av" from "node_modules\react-native-gifted-chat\lib\ExpoMessageVideo.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Answer (score 1):

@Jaime, I had the same issue.
I did the following and the issue is resolved

What did I do?

1.In my computer, opened the command prompt
2.changed the directory to the project directory
3.In the command prompt, ran the following command 
***expo install expo-av***
4.Closed the command prompt
5.Started the project , ran the simulator and could see the app running

Comment: @ Jaime, wanted to follow up whether my answer helped in resolution